# Kafka Connect + Camel + S3 sink: keyName attribute behavior

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-camel, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to use Camel S3 sink connector within Kafka Connect.
I would like to be able to configure S3 object key based on Kafka message key.
However **keyName** attribute doesn't behave the way I expected.

This is my connector configuration:

```json
{
  "connector.class": "org.apache.camel.kafkaconnector.awss3sink.CamelAwss3sinkSinkConnector",
  "camel.kamelet.aws-s3-sink.overrideEndpoint": true,
  "camel.kamelet.aws-s3-sink.uriEndpointOverride": "http://localstack:4566",
  "camel.kamelet.aws-s3-sink.bucketNameOrArn": "outbox",
  "camel.kamelet.aws-s3-sink.region": "eu-west-1",
  "camel.kamelet.aws-s3-sink.accessKey": "test",
  "camel.kamelet.aws-s3-sink.secretKey": "test",
  "camel.kamelet.aws-s3-sink.keyName": "adjlaksdlaksdj",
  "topics": "outbox.s3",
  "value.converter": "io.debezium.converters.BinaryDataConverter",
  "xxx": "xxx"
}
```

Whatever I put into **camel.kamelet.aws-s3-sink.keyName** attribute, the key in S3 becomes some machine string like **3A63F047E2E0AE2-0000000000000006**.
My understanding was that I should be able to configure S3 object key using this attribute using some expression language.
Is there any setting I can apply to fix this?

Comment: Where are you seeing documentation for that value? https://camel.apache.org/camel-kafka-connector/1.0.x/reference/connectors/camel-aws-s3-sink-kafka-sink-connector.html Also, why should this work? If you set a static file name, then all Kafka records only write to that file. Use Confluent S3 sink with FieldPartitioner if you really want to separate data by record values

Comment: Can you please report the version of the connector you're using?

Comment: I am using version 3.18.2
https://camel.apache.org/camel-kafka-connector/3.18.x/reference/connectors/camel-aws-s3-sink-kafka-sink-connector.html